# Using same SQLitedatabase data with any device in application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I tried installing my application to a 2nd Android device and it's not uploading the same database from my original device.For example on the original device I registered a Username into my database and then on the 2nd device I registered a username and the first Username I registered does not show up in the Admin activity I made that shows a list of registered users.

I thought it might of been the fact that the 2nd device I'm using is a Gingerbread version 2.3.4 while my first device is a Jelly Bean 4.2 but I used an emulator using Jelly Bean 4.2 and it wasn't showing the registered usernames of devices 1 and 2.

Is there a way I could make multiple devices share the same database in my application?

Forgot to include that the 2nd device is registered to a different google account if that makes a different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local data cannot arbitrarily be shared between devices. If you want to share the same data, you will need a server to act as a middleman.

In such a scenario, each device will have a local database, which will be synced with your server. So whenever a change is made on the device, a corresponding change is made on the server, and the other device then reads the updated database from the server and updates its own local copy.

Comment: How would I acquire a server to use my database with?Do you have any recommended websites that provide this?